# getting not a number(NaN) error html/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting NaN error while clicking radio button first. The page have a3 radio button when I click that 1st button it saya NaN and remaining 2 buttons has no response

this is my HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="totalamount" id="totalamount" value="<?php echo get_total_amount();?>" /

<input type="radio" name="rmr"  id="payment1" value="3" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" />
<input type="radio" name="rmr"  id="payment2" value="5.5" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" />
<input type="radio" name="rmr"  id="payment4" value="10" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" />
<div id="finalamount">
</div>
```

also I have mentioned my JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('input[name=rmr]').click(function () {  
        //make sure one is checked    
        if($('input[name=rmr]:checked').length > 0) {    
            $('#finalamount').html($("#totalamount").val() * $("input[name=rmr]:checked").val());    
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: can you clarify? where do you get the Nan in #totalamount? do you have the code of "updatepayment"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things:

1) As you're using the amount from the "totalamount" element, one has to ask: Are you *sure* that

```
value="<?php echo get_total_amount();?>"
```

...is outputting a valid number? Because if not, then the code

```
$('#finalamount').html($("#totalamount").val() * $("input[name=rmr]:checked").val());
```

...will indeed result in `NaN`. The `*` operator will try to convert both of its operands from strings to numbers, and of course if the value output by that PHP code isn't a valid number (for instance, if it's "$0.00" or something), the result of the conversion will be `NaN`. And `NaN` times *anything* is `NaN`.

[This example](http://jsbin.com/amolu3/2) of an invalid amount in the "totalamount" element yields something that looks a *lot* like the behavior you describe. *(That code isn't identical to yours, I did some very light refactoring, see below. But for the purposes of demoing an invalid number, it doesn't matter.)*

2) There's no `>` at the end of that hidden input in the text of your question. If you did a direct copy-and-paste, I wonder if that could be the problem?

3) As you're using jQuery, there's no need for the `onclick` attributes. Instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $("input[name=rmr]").click(function(){
        var checked = $("input[name=rmr]:checked");
        updatePayment(this.value);
        if (checked.length > 0) { // make sure one is checked
        {    
            $("#finalamount").html( $("#totalamount").val() * checked.val() );    
        } 
    }); 
});
```

...assuming you want `updatePayment` called every time.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/amolu3)

Folding `updatePayment` into the main `click` behavior lets you avoid any issues that may exist with the order in which DOM0 (`onclick` attribute) handlers and DOM2 handlers (the ones used with jQuery) are called.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me. Please find the working code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QMX8B/). You have to make sure that the value in the `totalamount` input is a numeric value. You can user `parseFloat()` to convert the string value into a float value.
Ex

```
 parseFloat($("#totalamount").val()) * $("input[name=rmr]:checked").val()
```

As [@Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584244/getting-not-a-numbernan-error-html-js/4584331#4584315) `parseFloat()` is not necessary since javascript take care of the type conversions.

You try to put an `alert()`/`console.log()` command before the calculation to see whether the `totalAmount` is having an non-numeric value. Ex: `alert($("#totalamount").val())`

Comment: You don't *need* to use `parseFloat` there, the `*` will coerce its operands. I'm not saying it's a bad idea, but it's not *necessary*. (Section 11.5 of the spec.)

Comment: @Crowder yes you are absolutely correct, js will automatically cast try to cast the value to numeric type if it is an arithmetica operation