# problem with jquery for add cart button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

hi i have a problem with displaying amount.i have the page called make payment in this page i made three radio buttons, if i click the button that amount must add with addcart like a product.

```
<form method="post" form name="make_payment_frm" action="module/make-payment-module.php" onsubmit="return show_make_payment_validation();" >

    <form id='theForm'>
    <input type="hidden" name="totalamount" id="totalamount" value="1" />
input type="radio" name="rmr"  id="payment1" value="3" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)" />
input type="radio" name="rmr"  id="payment2" value="5.5" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)"/>
input type="radio" name="rmr"  id="payment4" value="10" onclick="updatepayment(this.value)"/>
div id="finalamount">
/div>
```

i think that problem is my js script. if i click that button there is no response. how do i solve that problem
you guys can give me any idea

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cart :radio[name='rmr']").add(".cart :radio[name='rmr']").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(".cart :radio[name='rmr']").add(".cart :radio[name='rmr']").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("checked", false);
            });
            $(this).attr("checked", true);
        });
    });
})
    function updatePayment(val) {
      $("<p/>").html("updatePayment(" + val + ")").appendTo(document.body);
    }
```

thanks.have a nice day

Comment: what are you trying to do? what problem are you having?

Comment: Do you have an account called [nancy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/559032/nancy) as well? Because [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584244/getting-not-a-numbernan-error-html-js) looks *awfully* similar to this one and your others. If so, why?

Comment: You are not really using jQuery in its most useful way since you have all those `onclick` attributes. I fyou are using jQuery let it do its job!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you seem to be implementing the selecting and un-selecting of radio buttons in jQuery, surely HTML will handle that correctly for you.

However if you are using jQuery, do away with those `onclick` attributes since that is the benefit of jQuery and achieve the same result as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('.cart :radio[name="rmr"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            updatePayment(this.value);
    });
});
```

This will attach a change event to every radio button input with the attribute `name="rmr"`. Thus when the client clicks a new radio button, the value of two radio buttons will change, and the one that is then selected will call the `updatePayment` function with its value.

Comment: @jessy I think it should have been `:checked` and not `:selected`, I have changed my answer. Also try putting in some `alert('here')` statements in various places and see if the code is actually getting called.

Comment: @marcus i did not give any alert here. u understand my question. when customer clicks the radio it must add with add cart.. kindly visit my page www.spsmobile.co.uk then click makepayment

Comment: let you know about my problem mr.marcus

Comment: @jessy Firstly, I know you don't want to have alerts on your page, the point was to determine and narrow down the possible causes of your problem. Secondly I visited [www.spsmobile.co.uk](http://www.spsmobile.co.uk) and there was nothing on the page with the word "payment" on it.

Comment: @marcus http://spsmobile.co.uk/make-payment.php this is the page. in this page you can see delivery mail details with radio buttons.that button has different amont values.what i want is when customer clicks it must be add with like a product and then display the total amount that page.

Comment: @jessy There is nothing on that page with the class `cart`. When I removed `.cart` from the selector in my answer leaving `:radio[name="rmr"]` then it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @marcus for update the totall amount what should i do. here there is no need for store in DB..that value go to YOUR CART.what action i have to do it for clicks that button move to YOURCART

Comment: @jessy I cannot create you whole site for you. To update the amount I would select the span `var $amount = $('.repair-finalamount-txt');` and then set its value to an appropriate value based upon the radio button value which was just selected. For example: `$amount.text('£ 2.00');`

Comment: @jeessy I just realised I have been saying @jessy and its @jeessy. Sorry.